# Is there a gpio readall utility for Pi5?

Tags: gpio, pi-5

Is there a workable replacement for the `gpio readall` utility for Pi5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When wiringpi was deprecated I wrote a replacement `gpioreadall` to display gpio status.
This came in a few versions which used a number of gpio libraries none of which work on Pi5.

I wrote a library independent version using the `raspi-gpio` utility which worked on Raspberry Pi OS but did not work on Bookworm.
I then wrote a version using the `pinctrl` utility to work on Bookworm - expecting this to work on Pi5. For some inexplicable reason the Pi5 version of `pinctrl` differs from the Pi4 version!

I have now updated this to work on Pi4/Pi5 and also works on earlier models/OS.

The Pi5 version is slightly different (because it doesn't know mode or value of unallocated pins which are show as blank).

The code can be downloaded from [GPIOreadall](https://github.com/Milliways2/GPIOreadall)

[image: Pi5]

[image: Pi4B]

[image: Pi3B+]